# sql query to select data from excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When running a SQL query to select data from excel I get this error :

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

when executing this query in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP1 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\Students.xls',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Comment: Is your app 64-bit? There's no 64-bit provider for `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

You issue a select using the OPENROWSET and the OleDb Provider against a text file, in your case:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP1 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\Students.xls',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

First of all, for xlsx files (Excel 2007-2010) you can use the ACE oledb provider instead of the JET

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\PB.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

If that doesn't work the jet engine must be installed on the server. Installing MS Office on the server sorts that out.

The path to the xls is relative to the server, not the workstation you're running the command from the account that runs the SQL server service must have write access to the folder where the xls is. One possible solution is to changing the temp= and tmp= environment variables of the service startup account (eg. Administrator) to (for example) c:\temp, then enable Full Control on c:\temp to Everyone

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
5....

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', N'AllowInProcess', 0 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', N'DynamicParameters', 0
GO 


Select * 
into [temp_table$]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\temp\EXPENDITURE REPORT.xls;HDR=YES;IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [EXPENDITURE SHEET$]')
```